# jboss-cli property format for path attribute

Tags: properties, wildfly-10, jboss-eap-7, jboss-cli

As explained in [JBoss EAP 7 documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/management_cli_guide/#property_substitution), one can pass in a properties file to the CLI instance with the `--properties` flag.

I'm trying to create a generic script for logging profiles.

This is my properties file:

```
profilename=myProfileName
filepath=/some/dir/somefile.log
```

And this is my script:

```
set profilename=${profilename} 
set filepath=${filepath} 

/profile=full-ha/subsystem=logging/logging-profile=$profilename:add
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=logging/logging-profile=$profilename/periodic-size-rotating-file-handler=myHandler:add(file={"relative-to" => "some.dir","path" => $filepath},suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd,max-backup-index=50,rotate-on-boot=true,rotate-size=20m)
```

The script doesn't generate any error and completes successfully, and the `$profilename` variable is correctly replaced by its value.

But the `$filepath` variable seems to be a problem:

```
<logging-profile name="myProfileName">
    <periodic-size-rotating-file-handler name="myHandler" rotate-on-boot="true">
        <file relative-to="some.dir" path="$filepath}"/>
        <rotate-size value="20m"/>
        <max-backup-index value="50"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    </periodic-size-rotating-file-handler>
</logging-profile>
```

What is the specific format to use so that a variable can be used for the path attribute?

---

Edit: tested with JBoss EAP 7.2, and now it works as expected, so I guess it was indeed a bug.

Comment: It looks like maybe it's just a typo. You've got `$filepath}` and it should be `${filepath}`. Note the missing `{` after the `$`.

Comment: No, 100% sure it's not a typo, see the script: `"path" => $filepath`.

Comment: Sorry yes. The trailing `}` was for the `file` attribute. I just misread it. It is a bit odd though that the `path` in the XML is `$filepath}`. It could be a bug in CLI. Could you try using `"path" => "$filepath"`?

Comment: Tried `set path="$filepath"` with the same result: `path="$filepath}"`. `set "path" => "$filepath"` gave me `'=' is missing for variable '"path"'`, while `set "path" = "$filepath"` gave `Parameter '' is missing value.`.

Comment: This looks like a bug then.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late answer, but is the filepath variable last one in your list ?
Because this seems like a line ending issue if add new line at the end this would get picked up correctly.